# Codeigniter's `where` and `or_where`

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to specify a query in my model

```
$this->db
        ->select('*')
        ->from('library')
        ->where('library.rating >=', $form['slider'])
        ->where('library.votes >=', '1000')
        ->where('library.language !=', 'German')
        ->where('library.available_until >=', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))
        ->or_where('library.available_until =', "00-00-00 00:00:00")
        ->where('library.release_year >=', $year_start)
        ->where('library.release_year <=', $year_end)
        ->join('rating_repo', 'library.id = rating_repo.id')
```

So, the trouble i'm having is with my `or_where`. I want the `or` to be restricted to only the `available_until` field. Currently, however, i'm getting results which have a language of German which isn't what i want. How do i restrict my `or_where` filter to the `available_until` field only?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can modify just the two lines:

```
->where('(library.available_until >=', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), FALSE)
->or_where("library.available_until = '00-00-00 00:00:00')", NULL, FALSE)
```

EDIT:

Omitting the `FALSE` parameter would have placed the backticks before the brackets and make them a part of the table name/value, making the query unusable.

The `NULL` parameter is there just because the function requires the second parameter to be a value, and since we don't have one, we send NULL.

Comment: So this works now, but i don't know why. Can you explain please? I know that `false` prevents the addition of backticks to the query. I don't understand, though, how this has any bearing on this query - i'm also not sure what the `null` param does

Comment: This method works but can't be a standard for nice code. You may not use unclosed pharantesis in where clauses.

Answer (score 28):

You may group your **library.available_until** wheres area by **grouping** method of Codeigniter for without disable escaping where clauses.

```
$this->db
    ->select('*')
    ->from('library')
    ->where('library.rating >=', $form['slider'])
    ->where('library.votes >=', '1000')
    ->where('library.language !=', 'German')
    ->group_start() //this will start grouping
    ->where('library.available_until >=', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))
    ->or_where('library.available_until =', "00-00-00 00:00:00")
    ->group_end() //this will end grouping
    ->where('library.release_year >=', $year_start)
    ->where('library.release_year <=', $year_end)
    ->join('rating_repo', 'library.id = rating_repo.id')
```

Reference: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping

Answer (score 17):

You can change your code to this:

```
$where_au = "(library.available_until >= '{date('Y-m-d H:i:s)}' OR library.available_until = '00-00-00 00:00:00')";
$this->db
    ->select('*')
    ->from('library')
    ->where('library.rating >=', $form['slider'])
    ->where('library.votes >=', '1000')
    ->where('library.language !=', 'German')
    ->where($where_au)
    ->where('library.release_year >=', $year_start)
    ->where('library.release_year <=', $year_end)
    ->join('rating_repo', 'library.id = rating_repo.id');
```

Tip: to watch the generated query you can use

```
echo $this->db->last_query(); die();
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use :
Query grouping allows you to create groups of WHERE clauses by **enclosing them in parentheses**. This will allow you to create queries with complex WHERE clauses. Nested groups are supported. Example:

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('my_table')
        ->group_start()
                ->where('a', 'a')
                ->or_group_start()
                        ->where('b', 'b')
                        ->where('c', 'c')
                ->group_end()
        ->group_end()
        ->where('d', 'd')
->get();
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping

Comment: The question and proposed answers all make use of parentheses, so you not adding anything new. If you’re going to add a code example, you might at least adapt it to the questioners scenario. The code in this case is not helpful.

Answer (score 4):

```
$this->db->where('(a = 1 or a = 2)');
```