# SQL query using activerecords

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-3

I want to convert the following SQL query to codeIgniter active records format

```
SELECT * FROM `relation`
WHERE (`user1` = 144 OR `user2` = 144)
AND `status` = 2
AND `action` != 1
```

My attempt was something like this,

```
$ID=144;
$this->db->where('user1', $ID);
$this->db->or_where('user2', $ID);
$this->db->where('status', 2);
$this->db->where('action!=', 1);
```

However the results are not compatible. Can you point what is off here?

I would also be fine with suggestions not specifically using active records for the query.

Comment: You can follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498693/codeigniters-where-and-or-where

Comment: If you need prepared statement, you can also use query bindings with that: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your are using `OR` between multiple condition you must have to enclosed this in bracket. Change your code as below:

```
$this->db->where('(user1', $ID,FALSE);
$this->db->or_where("user2 = $ID)",NULL,FALSE);
$this->db->where('status', 2);
$this->db->where('action!=', 1);
```

Comment: Chose this as the selected answer because it is a more flexible and straight forward conversion.

Answer (score 3):

the correct query would be

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select('*')
    ->from('relation')
    ->group_start()
        ->where('user1', $ID)
        ->or_where('user2', $ID)
    ->group_end()
    ->where('status', 2)
    ->where('action !=', 1)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

**Hope this will help you :**

```
$ID = 144;
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('relation');
$this->db->where('user1', $ID);
$this->db->or_where('user2', $ID);
$this->db->where('status', '2');
$this->db->where('action !=', '1');

$query = $this->db->get();
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
  print_r($result);
  //return $query->result();  
}
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Comment: I was not clear in my original post, but I was stuck in translating the selection logic, and not on the retrieval.